# How to interpret the URL parameter in the cron.yaml file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS worker environment, I would like to apply a *cron.yaml* in parallel with an *application.py* file. The *cron.yaml* should execute at periodic intervals a data processing pipeline, that will be a Python script. In the documentation on the web, I often see something like the following in the cron.yaml file, but I am at odds what the url parameter exactly means for the data structure.

```
version: 1
cron: 
- name: "every-30-minutes-task"
  url: "/task1"
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
- name: "every-hour-task"
  url: "/task2"
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
```

Does it mean that there is a folder « task1 » and inside there should be a separate file with the script (for ex. app.py), that executes the scheduled cron job, and if so, which name should it have. Or should everything be put in a single script in the root?

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be a POST route. That means when a POST request is sent to `www.yourdomain.com/task1`, the logic of the controller associated to this route will be executed. So, what you have to do is to set up a controller which will call your script.